# How to retrieve strings from resource files for all the languages VB6

Tags: vb6

Is there a way to retrieve strings for all the languages available in a resource file? I just got a requirement for showing labels in 2 languages at the same time.

Comment: Are you trying to read from the built-in VB6 embedded resource, which is typically edited via the Resource plugin?

Comment: Yes. I started to edit the .Res file using the Resource Editor, adding several string tables.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two approaches if you want to use the standard VB6 resource files.

The first is to define each language version of the string by a range in the resource file.  So say you had a class to wrap up the string like this:

```
'In Class clsLocalizedStrings

Public Enum StringIds
   UserNameCaption = 1
   PasswordCaption
   OkayCaption
   CancelCaption
End Enum

Public Enum LocaleIds
   English = 1000
   French = 2000
   Spanish = 3000
End Enum

Private mLangId As LocaleIds

Public Property Get CurrentLanguge() As LocaleIds
   CurrentLanguge = mLangId 
End Property
Public Property Let CurrentLanguge(ByVal newVal As LocaleIds)
   mLangId = newVal 
End Property

Public Function GetLocalString(ByVal id As StringIds)
   Dim lResStrId As Long
   lResStrId = mLangId + id
   GetLocalString = LoadResString(lResStrId)
End Function
```

You could then set the CurrentLanguge at will and fetch the string value.

---

The alternative way, where each language gets its own resource file, is to create an ActiveX dll project for each language.  Each of these project would expose just a single class similar to the one above.  Ideally, you have a default language to use as a base, and the other reference it to implement the class:

```
'In Class LocalizedStrings in Project DefaultResources (with its own English resource file)

Public Enum StringIds
   UserNameCaption = 1
   PasswordCaption
   OkayCaption
   CancelCaption
End Enum

Public Function GetLocalString(ByVal id As StringIds)
   GetLocalString = LoadResString(id)
End Function


'In Class FrenchStrings in Project FrenchResources (with its own French resource file)

Implements DefaultResources

Public Function DefaultResources_GetLocalString(ByVal id As DefaultResources.StringIds)
   DefaultResources_GetLocalString= LoadResString(id)
End Function
```

Then in your main application you reference these dlls and make them available in a class or module:

```
'In Class clsLocalization in main app project

Public Enum LocaleIds
   English = 1
   French = 2
   Spanish = 3
End Enum

Private mLangId As LocaleIds
Private mResources() as DefaultResources

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Redim mResources (1 to 3)
   Set mResources(1) = DefaultResources.LocalizedStrings 'assumes english is default, easy to change though
   Set mResources(2) = FrenchResources.FrechStrings
   Set mResources(3) = SpanishResources.SpanishStrings
End Sub

Public Property Get CurrentLanguge() As LocaleIds
   CurrentLanguge = mLangId 
End Property
Public Property Let CurrentLanguge(ByVal newVal As LocaleIds)
   mLangId = newVal 
End Property

Public Function GetLocalString(ByVal id As StringIds)
   GetLocalString = mResources(mLangId).GetLocalString(id)
End Function

Public Propert Get Langauge(ByVal langId As LocaleIds)
   Return mResources(langId)
End Property
```

And this in a module:

```
Global Localization As clsLocalization
```

Thn you use it like this:

```
'show caption for current languge
MsgBox Localization.GetLocalString(StringIds.UserCaption)

'show caption for explicit languge
MsgBox Localization.Langauge(French).GetLocalString(StringIds.UserCaption)
MsgBox Localization.Langauge(Spanish).GetLocalString(StringIds.UserCaption)
```

Hope that helps!